# Printing and check if there is duplicate

Tags: java

I would like to get your expert advice. If I input a product code, I would like to check if there is a product code in the file. If there is any, I will not write it in the file, but if there is the product code does not exist, the system will print it in the file.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Grocery adminObject = new Grocery();
Grocery adminObject1 = new Grocery();
ArrayList<Grocery> groceryRecord = new ArrayList<Grocery>();

do {
    System.out.println("1. Add Grocery Item");
    System.out.println("2. Delete Grocery Item");
    System.out.println("3. Update Grocery Item");
    System.out.println("4. Search Grocery Item");
    System.out.println("5. Bill Report");
    System.out.println("6. Exit");
    
    System.out.print("Please Enter Required Option from 1 - 6: ");
    choice = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    
    switch (choice){
        case 1:
            do {
                System.out.println("Product Number: ");
                adminObject.setProductCode(input.nextInt());
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Name of the Product: ");
                adminObject.setName(input.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Price: ");
                adminObject.setPrice(input.nextDouble());
                System.out.println("Quantity: ");
                adminObject.setQuantity(input.nextDouble());
                System.out.println("Tax Percent: ");
                adminObject.setTax(input.nextDouble());
                System.out.println("Discount Percent: ");
                adminObject.setDiscount(input.nextDouble());
                input.nextLine();
                
                System.out.println("Do you want to save the file? ");
                choice_1 = input.nextLine();
                choice_1 =choice_1.toUpperCase();
                if(choice_1.equals("YES")||choice_1.equals("Y")){
                try(BufferedWriter groceryFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("grocery.txt", true));  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("grocery.txt"))) {
                String currentLine = reader.readLine();

            while (currentLine != null)
            {
                String[] groceryDetail = currentLine.split(",");

                adminObject1.setProductCode(Integer.parseInt(groceryDetail[0]));
                            adminObject1.setName(groceryDetail[1]);
                            adminObject1.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(groceryDetail[2]));
                            adminObject1.setQuantity(Double.parseDouble(groceryDetail[3]));
                            adminObject1.setTax(Double.parseDouble(groceryDetail[4]));
                            adminObject1.setDiscount(Double.parseDouble(groceryDetail[5]));

                groceryRecord.add(new Grocery (adminObject1.getProductCode(), adminObject1.getName(), adminObject1.getPrice(), adminObject1.getQuantity(),adminObject1.getTax(),adminObject1.getDiscount()));
               
                currentLine = reader.readLine();
            }
        
          if(adminObject1.getProductCode()==adminObject.getProductCode()){
                System.out.println("Duplicate Product Code.. Please re-enter");
            }
            else {
              
               groceryFile.write(adminObject.getProductCode() + "," + adminObject.getName() + "," + adminObject.getPrice() + "," + adminObject.getQuantity() + "," + adminObject.getTax() + "," + adminObject.getQuantity() + "\n");
            }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask? What is the problem with your code? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if currentline contains input product code

```
String currentLine = reader.readLine(); 
if(currentLine.contains("productCode")){

}
```

Comment: He used `input.nextInt()` for taking product code mans the product code is in integer not in string

Comment: Thank you @sanjeevRm for your message. My class variables are as follows: How can I check duplicate with int data type     
     private int productCode;
    private String name;
    private double price, quantity, tax, discount, netAmount;

After the readLine I put an if statement but it doesnt capture the duplicate. It still write it in the file instead of ignoring it.

Comment: can you print currentLine and check if it contains duplicate product code